# Multiple data source with same entity

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, datasource

Currently working on a project where my Spring Boot project needs to connect to 6 data sources that are all the same but they are on different servers.

I create Persistence and JPA repositories for each of them but execute data from the wrong one(from the first one).

> replace *** with server name (e.x DE4)

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource({"classpath:application.properties"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "com.mohkhz.vpnmanager.Repository.XUIRepository.***.XUIRepository_***",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "xuiEntityManager_***",
        transactionManagerRef = "xuiTransactionManager_***"
)
public class PersistenceXUIConfiguration_*** {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean xuiEntityManager_***() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(xuiDataSource_***());
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[]{"com.mohkhz.vpnmanager.Model.Entity.x_ui"});

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("hibernate.ddl-auto", "update");
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("spring.jpa.generate-ddl", "true");
        properties.put("spring.jpa.show-sql", "true");
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        properties.put("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql", "true");

        em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);

        System.out.println("connected to ***");

        return em;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource xuiDataSource_***() {

        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.xui.***.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.xui.***.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.xui.***.password"));

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager xuiTransactionManager_***() {

        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(xuiEntityManager_***().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```